# Syntax problem with quotes in PHP and HTML

Tags: php, html, syntax, quotes

I have this php code

```
echo "<textarea id='textarea' cols='70' rows='5' name='code'>".$code."</textarea>";
```

and I need to put this `onClick="SelectAll('txtarea');"` after `id='textarea'` but the quotes are messing me up and I cant figure it out.

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
`echo "<textarea id='textarea' onClick=\"SelectAll('txtarea');\" cols='70' rows='5' name='code'>".$code."</textarea>";`

Answer (score 5):

**Explaination**

You will need to escape the double quotes, so they will not be read as PHP code. You can do this by typing a `\` character before them. You can read more about escaping characters in PHP [here](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php7p7.html).
**Edit your code to this**

```
echo "<textarea id='textarea' onClick=\"SelectAll('txtarea');\" cols='70' rows='5' name='code'>".$code."</textarea>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can escape quotes with the backslash char "\". Try something like that:

```
echo "<textarea id=\"textarea\"></textarea>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try use [Escape Character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) \" ?

So it would be

```
onClick=\"SelectAll('txtarea');\"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<textarea id='textarea' onClick='SelectAll(\"txtarea\");' cols='70' rows='5' name='code'>".$code."</textarea>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use \" instead of " within your text.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
echo "<textarea id='textarea' cols='70' onClick=\"SelectAll('txtarea');\"  rows='5' name='code'>".$code."</textarea>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the quotes using backslash, so put in onClick=\"SelectAll('txtarea')\"

Same is recommended for the other attributes, e.g. cols=\"70\"

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make it easier on yourself? If you need single and double quotes within your string, you can use [heredoc syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), such as:

```
echo <<<EOF
<textarea id="textarea" cols="70" onClick="SelectAll('txtarea');" rows="5" name="code">$code</textarea>
EOF;
```